# Extras Folder Accidentally Deleted - Android SDK

Tags: android, sdk, extras

I accidentally deleted some of the plugins inside Extras Folder in Android SDK. Coz it looks broke. Now my problem is I dont know how to recover it. And my android emulator is not working coz it cant select device that the Google provides. Can someone tell me what to do.

Answer (score 1):

Just open the [SDK Manager](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/sdk-manager.html) and redownload the missing things.

Comment: the problem is, theres nothing that says its missng or its uninstalled. It was deleted entirely.

Comment: try to restart the sdk manager entirely to recognize the missing parts.

Answer (score 1):

You can download whatever gets deleted using  [Android SDK Manager](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/sdk-manager.html)

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure you can patch your install with the packages from the SDK download: [http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html]

Once you have downloaded the package install the sdk and all the required API's. These are the stand-alone Android SDK Tools. The packages provide the basic SDK tools for app development.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. In my case, **I have been deleted android support library** accidentally. When I want to re-install this package, it not show in list of my extras in Android SDK Manager.

If I run my Android SDK Manager from Eclipse, the missing packages not shown. But when I go to my SDK directory and manually run SDKManager.exe as administrator, It's work. 
[image]

and the result is : 
[image]